# Error 404 when using navigator.sendBeacon to log out a user

Tags: javascript, node.js, beacon

hi In my application if the user closes the tab/window I would like to log him out. For this purpose I use `navigator.sendBeacon` in the following way:

`client.js`:

```
window.addEventListener('unload', logData, false);
function logData() {
    var b = localStorage.localStor;
    if (b != null && b != "{}") {
        console.log("closed");
        console.log(JSON.parse(b).email); //prints user email
        navigator.sendBeacon("/log", { email: JSON.parse(b).email });
        localStorage.clear();
    }
}
```

`server.js`: (node.js)

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var fs = require('fs');

var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {

    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE");
    var url_parts = url.parse(request.url);
    var path = url_parts.path;
    var postBody = [];  //for post uses
    if (path === "/log") {
        console.log("looging out"); // doesn't appear in node.js commad line
        postBody = [];
        request.on('data', (chunk) => {
            postBody.push(chunk);
        }).on('end', () => {
            postBody = Buffer.concat(postBody).toString();
            var parsedData = JSON.parse(postBody);
            var emailIndex = usersList.findIndex(function (element) {
                return element.email === parsedData.email;
            });
            console.log("length before :" + usersList.length); //nothing appear
            usersList.splice(emailIndex, 1);
            console.log("length before :" + usersList.length); //nothing appear

        });
    }
```

In the app I display the number of current connected users using `settimeout` every 30 seconds the length of `usersList` ,but when closing the window the localStorage is indeed clear but the user is still connected because the number of connected users doesn't change . It clearly appears that somehow sendBeacon does not go to the server or it goes but does not apply the condition `if (path === "/log")`. Also after closing the tab I get the following error in the termenal (I work in Visual Code):

> "POST /log" Error (404): "Not found"

I searched about how to use sendbeacon and I used it as in [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon), but I think that the request does not go to the server because of the error I get.

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to make sure if you receive the request on nodejs server or not. And if you do receive what is the `request path` in it. If even you're not sure about it, how can some remote person guide you.

Comment: @Shaharyar No I don't recieve the request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every thing is right but sendBeacon should be like this:

```
navigator.sendBeacon("http://localhost:8080/log", { email: JSON.parse(b).email });
```